# how to pass textbox value to next jsp page by clicking on a different form button without using javascript

Tags: html, jsp

here is my code

```
<body>
<input type=text name=name>
<form action=new3.jsp method=post name="f1">
<input type=text name=name>
<input type=submit value=next>
</form>
<form action=new1.jsp method=post>
<input type=submit value=back>
</form>
</body>
```

as you can see there are two forms here with two different submit buttons named "next" and "back". The text box is in the form where "next" button is. My question is here how to send the value of this text box to "new1.jsp" clicking "back button" without using javascript. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't post form to JSPs. Post the to servlets instead, and let the server analyze the parameters and forward to the appropriate JSP depending on which button has been clicked:

```
<form action="/controllerServlet" method="post" name="f1">
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="submit" name="destination" value="next"/>
    <input type="submit" name="destination" value="back"/>
</form>
```

Using the above form (which BTW, is valid HTML), the servlet can use the value of the "destination" parameter. If it's "next", it should forward to `new3.jsp`. If it's `back`, it should forward to "new1.jsp". And if, for example, you want to redisplay the same page because the user didn't enter a valid value in the text field, it can do so.

That's the well-known MVC pattern. You should use it.

Comment: i am getting this error : the requested resource (/controllerServlet) is not available.